Should some tag synonyms (with many questions in both tags) be merged?
According to this SEDE query there are more that 950 tag synonyms having questions in both tags (essentially meaning they have not been merged). You can find such synonyms also in the list of all tag synonyms - if you look at the ones where the number of questions is shown in both columns.1
For those tags, one can find question tagged with the synonym (rather than with the master tag) using SEDE. Here is another query - if you only want question which are tagged with the synonym, but not with the master tag.2
This has several consequences—most important probably being that searching using combination and keywords only returns questions in the master tag—and never any questions which still have the synonym. So those questions are more difficult to search. (Of course, many users are unaware that they can use tags for searching, so they never run into this problem.)
This behavior was mentioned in several posts on various metas—I have posted links below.3 I will include some examples to illustrate this. I'd say that it is suboptimal that many questions are never returned in this type of search.
I am aware of the fact that merging tags is not reversible, so it should be used carefully. But at least for some of those synonyms it seems unlikely that they are going to be removed. Would it perhaps be better to merge the synonyms in clear-cut cases?
For example, these synonyms have still several thousand questions in the "old" tag, and I don't think they're likely to be cancelled:

The synonym int → integer (with more than 9k and 13k questions according to SEDE).4
The synonym rows → row (with more than 4k and 7k questions according to SEDE).5

Probably I should include the disclaimer that I do not visit SO frequently. But since there was discussion around this on some of the sites I frequent, it seemed reasonable to mention it here, too (especially considering the number of such tags on SO).

1And probably I should also mention the 83 tag synonyms where the target does not exist at all. Of those synonyms, 78 are Approved. See also: Broken behavior for unmerged tag synonym when there's no questions with target tag.
2See also: Is there a way (e.g. with SEDE) to find questions with an existing tag that's been synonymized (but not merged) into another tag?
3Some related posts, where you can see examples of this behavior:

On this meta: Converted tag synonym don't allow to filtering on converted tagged threads. There is also: How to find a question by its old tag when that tag is synonymized with another (This one was mentioned in the comments by Zoe.)
Meta Stack Exchange: What are differences between synonyms with and without merging from the practical point of view? and some of the questions linked there.
Mathematics Meta: What should be the general procedure for tags which are synonymized but not merged?
I have also mentioned some examples in this chatroom. An example related specifically to SO was mentioned here.

4You can see that integer shows 23263 question in the active tab and 13614 question in the newest tab.
For example, the question "Understanding SQL Server Int Data Types" has the tag int. But it is not returned when searching with the tag int.
5The tag row shows 12194 questions in the active tab and 7790 questions in the newest tab.
For example, this question is tagged row: Plotting excel data rows in matplotlib. And it is not returned when searching with this tag.

I wasn't sure whether to include the tag bug, but in some previous discussions I was told that the fact that the search does not find the questions tagged by the synonym is status-bydesign. (And the tag feature-request probably is not a very good fit either. The software already has a tool to do this—it is the question whether there is some consensus in the community about this, and if there is, the moderators can merge the tags where appropriate.)

Worth noting that at the moment, merging is required to work around a synonym/search bug where synonymised tags don't appear in search or on the  tag page. The main reason mergers don't happen is that there are roughly 1000 unmerged synonyms, which requires a lot of moderator time to process

@Zoe So that is actually considered a bug? I've been told that it is the expected behavior - for example here; or maybe, an unimportant edge case could be a better description. ("In practice, an unmerged tag synonym will behave incorrectly. The software is not really designed for this case. Ask a moderator to merge the tags.")

The search thing? Yes, and it has already been reported

I'm not sure it makes sense to talk about all the tags in the abstract, it would make more sense to take them on one at a time.  Obviously a lot more work, unfortunately.
